# How to get geolocation information in DotNetBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, dotnetbrowser

The local html is showed in the DotNetBrowser (C#, Visualstudio 2017)
An error will occur when running the following code of javascript.

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`

※Full of the sources of the website I want to show is below site
https://syncer.jp/how-to-use-geolocation-api

It works fine when displaying local html in IE and Chrome, but
error occurs when showed in DotNetbrowser.

Of course permission is granted.
(referred to [Providing Location information in DotNetBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870770))

I guess that there is a cause for DotNetBrowser's specifications or settings

Please tell me if there is a solution or a clear cause. m(_ _)m

Answer (score 0):

solved.

The google API was definitely needed.

https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110022-geolocation